# Obtener el total de todos los group by

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Saben cómo puedo obtener el total de un `GROUP BY`?. Me explico: se realiza una agrupación por plan y cada plan lleva su total; necesito obtener el total de todo eso.

Un ejemplo es

```
(plan) (cantidad usuarios no admin) costo plan   total
admin      5                            4         (5*4 = 20)
silver     7                            5         (7*5 = 35)
gold       20                           10        (10*20 = 200)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                            gran total =    255
```

Intente con ROLLUP PERO no funciona. me da un resultado erroneo

El gran total es lo que quiero obtener y ahora si ven eso ya saben que es por que cada uno tiene un costo diferente. Lo que necesito es el query que obtenga gran total.

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener un resultado exactamente igual a la tabla?, ¿O simplemente quieres obtener el gran total? Por cierto, tu multiplicación tiene un error (`7*5 = 35`).

Comment: Además, ¿podrías agregar una tabla ejemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar un `SELECT` anidado, ya que te permite separar las operaciones.

Por ejemplo, considera la siguiente tabla simple llamada `planes`:

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| id | plan   | usuarios | costo |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| 1  | admin  | 2        | 4     |
| 2  | admin  | 3        | 4     |
| 3  | silver | 1        | 5     |
| 4  | silver | 2        | 5     |
| 5  | silver | 4        | 5     |
| 6  | gold   | 5        | 10    |
| 7  | gold   | 8        | 10    |
| 8  | gold   | 4        | 10    |
| 9  | gold   | 3        | 10    |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
```

Para obtener únicamente el gran total, la consulta sería así:

```
SELECT
    SUM(total) AS total
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            plan,
            (SUM(usuarios) * MAX(costo)) AS total
        FROM
            planes
        GROUP BY
            plan
    ) planes;
```

Resultado

```
+--------+
| total  |
+--------+
| 255    |
+--------+
```

---

Si quieres obtener una tabla tal (casi) como la muestras en tu ejemplo, la consulta sería:

```
SELECT
    plan,
    SUM(usuarios) AS total_usuarios,
    MAX(costo) AS total_costo,
    SUM(total) AS total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            plan,
            usuarios,
            costo,
            (usuarios * costo) AS total
        FROM
            planes
    ) planes
GROUP BY
    plan
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Resultado:

```
+--------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| plan   | total_usuarios | total_costo | total |
+--------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| admin  | 5              | 4           | 20    |
| gold   | 20             | 10          | 200   |
| silver | 7              | 5           | 35    | 
| NULL   | 32             | 19          | 255   |
+--------+----------------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. con esta solucion logre dar. SELECT
    SUM(total) AS total
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            plan,
            (SUM(usuarios) * MAX(costo)) AS total
        FROM
            planes
        GROUP BY
            plan
    ) planes;

Answer (score 2):

Esta solución podría ser

```
select 
    sum(total) gran_total
from (
    select 
        plan,
        cantidad_usuarios,
        costo_plan,
        sum(cantidad_usuarios * costo_plan) total
    from
    tabla_movimiento
    group by plan
) consulta
```

pero no se porque haría falta pasar por un group by si es que se quiere sólo el gran total, el sql podría ser más simple:

```
    select 
        sum(cantidad_usuarios * costo_plan) gran_total
    from
    tabla_movimiento
```

también podes hacer una combinación entre ambas consultas:

```
    select 
        plan,
        cantidad_usuarios,
        costo_plan,
        sum(cantidad_usuarios * costo_plan) total
    from
    tabla_movimiento
    group by plan

    union all


    select 
        null plan,
        null cantidad_usuarios,
        null costo_plan,
        sum(cantidad_usuarios * costo_plan) total
    from
    tabla_movimiento
```

para obtener un resultado como éste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]